# Imagem desaparece depois da animação + window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou a construir um menu para o meu blog, encontrei alguns códigos na net, e estou a tentar implementar um deles. O problema é o seguinte: a imagem (logo) desaparece do menu (header) quando eu faço o seguinte:

1. encolho a janela para tamanho de um telemóvel
2. Abro o burger menu, volto a fechar
3. expando a janela

e puff... não tenho o logótipo. O que me está a escapar? Tenho em baixo o código:

### CSS

```
     /* Interface - Mobile */

    .fa:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    }

    header .bgMenu {
     height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    }

header.fixedMenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.navMenu {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}



.linksMenu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -4px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.linksMenu.showMenu {
  display: block;
  background-color: #148dcd;
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin-top: -2.25em;
}

.linksMenu a {
  color: #ECEFF1;
  text-align: left;
  font: 1em Oswald;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  padding: .8em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;


}

.linksMenu a:before {
  margin: 0 1em 0 .25em;
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(1) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.4);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(2) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.55);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(3) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.7);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(4) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.85);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(5) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,1);
}

.burgerMenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #148dcd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.burger {
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.burger::before {
  top: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.burger::after {
  bottom: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.burger::after, .burger::before, .burger {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 29px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Shade from Burger Menu */

.bgShade {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .25s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bgShade.showShade {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.bgShade.hideShade {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Scroll locked */

body.bodyStopped {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Transition from Burger menu to X */

.burgerMenu.showMenu .burger::after{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 0px;
}

.burgerMenu.showMenu .burger::before{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0px;
}

.burgerMenu.showMenu .burger{
  background: rgba(111,111,111,.0);
}

/* Interface - Desktop */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  header .bgMenu {
    background-color: rgba(20,141,205,1);
  }

  div.burgerMenu {
    display: none;
  }

  .navMenu {
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .linksMenu {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  }

  .linksMenu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .navMenu .linksMenu li a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0c547b;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 33px 1.2em 24px .8em;
    transition: .25s;
  }

  .navMenu .linksMenu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navMenu.bounceOutUp {
    animation-name: unset;
  }

  .figureProfile.animated.zoomInUp img {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: 360px;
  }

  .bgShade.fadeIn,
  .bgShade.fadeOut {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

### JQuerry

```
// Burger Menu transitions
var count = 0;
$(".burgerMenu").click(function() {
    count++;
    // Var to identify even or odd click
    var isEven = function(someNumber) {
        return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
    };
    // Odd clicks
    if (isEven(count) === false) {
        $("header").addClass("fixedMenu");
        $(".burgerMenu").addClass("showMenu");
        $(".linksMenu").addClass("showMenu");
        $(".navMenu").removeClass("bounceOutUp");
        $(".navMenu").addClass("bounceInDown");
        $(".bgShade").removeClass("hideShade");
        $(".bgShade").addClass("showShade");
        $("body").addClass("bodyStopped");
    }
    // Even clicks
    else if (isEven(count) === true) {

        //$("header").removeClass("fixedMenu"); 
        $(".burgerMenu").removeClass("showMenu");
        $(".navMenu").removeClass("bounceInDown");
        $(".navMenu").addClass("bounceOutUp");
        $(".bgShade").removeClass("showShade");
        $(".bgShade").addClass("hideShade");
        $("body").removeClass("bodyStopped");
    }
});



// Burger menu without one extra click
$('.linkHeader').click(function() {
    count++;
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="bgShade animated"></div>
            <header id="header" class="animated">


            <div class="bgMenu" style="background: #148dcd">

              <div style="padding:15px 0px 0px 15px; float:left;"><img src="http://www.doveloper.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/blog-logo-hover-300x90.png"
                height="60" width="200"></div>

                <div class="burgerMenu">
                <div class="burger"></div>

            </div>
            <nav class="navMenu animated">
            <ul class="linksMenu">
                <li class="cool-link" id="home-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-code">Início</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="articles-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-book">Artigos</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="courses-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-rocket">Cursos</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="tools-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-cog">Ferramentas</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="about-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-briefcase">Sobre</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Se quiserem ver por vocês é aqui: http://www.doveloper.com/

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema usando este "desvio":

```
    $(window).on('resize', function(){


    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
       $("#logo_mobile").css("display","block");
        $("#logo_desktop").css("display","none");

    }
    else {
          $("#logo_mobile").css("display","none");
        $("#logo_desktop").css("display","block");
    }

});
```

Assim garanto que a imagem volta a aparecer. Teoricamente isso quase nunca vai ser executado pois o utilizador geralmente não muda o tamanho da janela.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está adicionando a classe `.showMenu` ao elemento `$(".linksMenu")` quando o *burger* é aberto e não está removendo essa classe quando o *burger* é fechado. Desta forma, estava dando conflito nos elementos e deixando a `div` da logo *escondida*.

A solução é adicionar a linha abaixo no script, dentro do bloco `else if (isEven(count) === true) {` para remover a tal classe:

```
$(".linksMenu").removeClass("showMenu");
```

Outra coisa, é fazer uma função que feche o *burger* automaticamente (caso esteja aberto) quando o tamanho da janela for maior ou igual a 768px (mesmo tamanho referido no CSS em `@media`):

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
    if(window.innerWidth >= 768){
        $(".linksMenu").removeClass("showMenu");
        if($("nav.navMenu").hasClass("bounceInDown")){
            $(".burgerMenu").trigger("click");
        }
    }
});
```

```js
// Burger Menu transitions
var count = 0;
$(".burgerMenu").click(function() {
    count++;
    // Var to identify even or odd click
    var isEven = function(someNumber) {
        return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
    };
    // Odd clicks
    if (isEven(count) === false) {
        $("header").addClass("fixedMenu");
        $(".burgerMenu").addClass("showMenu");
        $(".linksMenu").addClass("showMenu");
        $(".navMenu").removeClass("bounceOutUp");
        $(".navMenu").addClass("bounceInDown");
        $(".bgShade").removeClass("hideShade");
        $(".bgShade").addClass("showShade");
        $("body").addClass("bodyStopped");
    }
    // Even clicks
    else if (isEven(count) === true) {

        //$("header").removeClass("fixedMenu"); 
        $(".burgerMenu").removeClass("showMenu");
        $(".linksMenu").removeClass("showMenu");
        $(".navMenu").removeClass("bounceInDown");
        $(".navMenu").addClass("bounceOutUp");
        $(".bgShade").removeClass("showShade");
        $(".bgShade").addClass("hideShade");
        $("body").removeClass("bodyStopped");
    }
});

$(window).on("load resize", function(){
 if(window.innerWidth >= 768){
        $(".linksMenu").removeClass("showMenu");
  if($("nav.navMenu").hasClass("bounceInDown")){
   $(".burgerMenu").trigger("click");
  }
 }
});

// Burger menu without one extra click
$('.linkHeader').click(function() {
    count++;
});
```

```css
/* Interface - Mobile */

    .fa:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    }

    header .bgMenu {
     height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    }

header.fixedMenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.navMenu {
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}



.linksMenu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: -4px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.linksMenu.showMenu {
  display: block;
  background-color: #148dcd;
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin-top: -2.25em;
}

.linksMenu a {
  color: #ECEFF1;
  text-align: left;
  font: 1em Oswald;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  padding: .8em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;


}

.linksMenu a:before {
  margin: 0 1em 0 .25em;
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(1) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.4);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(2) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.55);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(3) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.7);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(4) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,.85);
}

.linksMenu li:nth-child(5) a {
  background-color: rgba(0,116,166,1);
}

.burgerMenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #148dcd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
}

.burger {
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.burger::before {
  top: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.burger::after {
  bottom: 10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.burger::after, .burger::before, .burger {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 29px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Shade from Burger Menu */

.bgShade {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .25s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.bgShade.showShade {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.bgShade.hideShade {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

/* Scroll locked */

body.bodyStopped {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Transition from Burger menu to X */

.burgerMenu.showMenu .burger::after{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 0px;
}

.burgerMenu.showMenu .burger::before{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0px;
}

.burgerMenu.showMenu .burger{
  background: rgba(111,111,111,.0);
}

/* Interface - Desktop */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  header .bgMenu {
    background-color: rgba(20,141,205,1);
  }

  div.burgerMenu {
    display: none;
  }

  .navMenu {
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .linksMenu {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  }

  .linksMenu li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .navMenu .linksMenu li a {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0c547b;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 33px 1.2em 24px .8em;
    transition: .25s;
  }

  .navMenu .linksMenu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .navMenu.bounceOutUp {
    animation-name: unset;
  }

  .figureProfile.animated.zoomInUp img {
    max-width: inherit;
    width: 360px;
  }

  .bgShade.fadeIn,
  .bgShade.fadeOut {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bgShade animated"></div>
<header id="header" class="animated">
    <div class="bgMenu" style="background: #148dcd">
        <div style="padding:15px 0px 0px 15px; float:left;"><img src="http://www.doveloper.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/blog-logo-hover-300x90.png" height="60" width="200"></div>
        <div class="burgerMenu">
            <div class="burger"></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navMenu animated">
            <ul class="linksMenu">
                <li class="cool-link" id="home-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-code">Início</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="articles-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-book">Artigos</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="courses-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-rocket">Cursos</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="tools-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-cog">Ferramentas</a></li>
                <li class="cool-link" id="about-menu-button"><a href="#" class="fa fa-briefcase">Sobre</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```